# Разница между PUT и POST

Tags: put, post, http

Привет.

Стыдно признаться, но я прочитав много различных статей, все равно не до конца осознаю разницу между PUT и POST

> Спецификация HTTP 1.1 гласит, что PUT
> идемпотентен. Это значит, что клиент
> может выполнить множество PUT запросов
> по одному URI и это не приведет к
> созданию записей дубликатов. Операции
> присвоения — хороший пример
> идемпотентной операции
>
> String userId =
> this.request["USER_ID"];
>
> Даже если эту операцию выполнить
> дважды или трижды, никакого вреда не
> будет (кроме лишних тактов
> процессора). POST же с другой стороны
> не идемпотентен. Это что-то вроде
> инкремента. Вам следует использовать
> POST или PUT с учетом того является ли
> выполняемое действие идемпотентным или
> нет. Говоря языком программистов, если
> клиент знает URL объекта, который
> нужно создать, используйте PUT. Если
> клиент знает URL метода/класса
> создающего нужный объект, используйте
> POST.

Здесь приведен "хороший пример идемпотентной операции String userId = this.request["USER_ID"];". 
В чем пример хороший не пойму? Какой вред может быть от этой операции если мы используем POST а не PUT?
Был бы очень признателен, если бы мне дали простой пример, где лучше применять PUT и почему.

Например огромное число сервисов для загрузки файлов использует PUT. Чем это оправдано?

Меня интересует в частности загрузка файлов.

Comment: Словоблудие это все. 


С т.з. реальной программы, как сделал, так и будет. 

В любом случае (и PUT и POST) программа на сервере получает (в принципе) URL, заголовки и данные. И отправляет назад код результата, заголовки и данные.

Comment: PUT нигде не используется.

Comment: Так это же противоречит принципу бритвы Окамы "не наплоди лишних сущностей"

Comment: Я так понимаю, что *post* добавляет запись, у которой ещё нет идентификатора (ид), когда *put* оперирует существующими объектами (у которых есть ид).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Разница между PUT и POST - это вопрос семантики. Коль скоро для операций используются разные глаголы, то и смысл у них должен быть разным.

Представьте, что ваш сервис оперирует понятиями блокнот (notebook) и запись (post). Один блокнот может содержать множество записей.

Для **добавления** новой записи в блокнот c идентификатором **id** вы будете использовать метод **POST** с URL mydomain/notebooks/id/. Ваш сервис, ориентируясь на метод POST, сам присвоит нужный идентификатор записи, добавит ее в блокнот и вернет вам URL созданной записи (для доступа к записи по GET или для удаления по DELETE). При этом хорошо бы вернуть клиенту URL созданной записи.

Допустим, запись с идентификатором **post-id** уже создана и доступна по URL mydomain/notebooks/id/posts/post-id. Но клиент (владелец записи) исправил в ней ошибку и хочет **перезаписать** ее. Для этого он использует метод **PUT** с URL mydomain/notebooks/id/posts/**post-id** и передает обновленную запись в теле запроса. Ваш сервис, ориентируясь на метод PUT удаляет старую запись и записывает новую, при этом она доступна по тому же URL.

Конечно, никто не мешает вам всегда использовать метод POST (например HTML 4 позволял использовать только методы GET и POST). Но все же стоит придерживаться рекомендаций в целях единообразной трактовки методов всеми разработчиками.

**UPD:** Вспомнил еще кое-что. Рекомендуется использоваться метод POST для создания подчиненного ресурса (дочернего по отношению к другому ресурсу; пример блокнота и записи как раз очень подходит).

Comment: Спасибо, но я несколько не согласен, вот например тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/630475/1791282 наоборот для создания советуют использовать именно PUT, т.к POST в случае отсутствия объекта по URL даст ошибку.

Comment: @Sever я не согласен с автором ответа на SO. Метод PUT обладает свойством идемпотентности, а его рекомендации ведут к нарушению этого свойства.

Comment: Из rfc2068:

Фундаментальное различие между POST и PUT запросами, отражено в различном значении запрашиваемого URI (Request-URI). URI в запросе POST идентифицирует ресурс, который обрабатывает включенный объект. Этим ресурсом может быть процесс, принимающий данные, шлюз к некоторому другому протоколу, или отдельный объект, который принимает аннотации (accepts annotations). Напротив, URI в запросе PUT идентифицирует объект, включенный в запрос - агент пользователя назначает данный URI включенному ресурсу, а сервер НЕ ДОЛЖЕН пытаться применить запрос к некоторому другому ресурсу.

Comment: А тогда как быть с методом PATCH?

Comment: @ivan23 `PATCH` является расширением и не входит в стандарт. Так что вы вольны сами интерпретировать соответствующий RFC.

Answer (score 27):

Насколько я понимаю все это, то, если сравнить PUT и POST операциями в MySQL, то POST - это  INSERT, а PUT - UPDATE or INSERT

**by KES**

Расмотрим на примере форума. В нём есть темы и сообщения. Мы делаем запросы в тему hello

```
POST /topic/hello?message = Здесь

POST /topic/hello?message = был 

POST /topic/hello?message = Вася
```

Первый запрос создаст (**INSERT**) тему hello с сообщением "Здесь", остальные два запроса тоже создадут (**INSERT**) новые сообщения в теме. В результате у нас получится, что тема hello содержит: Здесь был Вася.

```
PUT /topic/hello?message = Здесь

PUT /topic/hello?message = был 

PUT /topic/hello?message = Вася
```

Первый запрос создаст (**INSERT**) тему hello с сообщением "Здесь", остальные два запроса обновят (**UPDATE**) сообщение в теме. В результате у нас получится, что тема hello содержит: Вася.

Идемпотентность **PUT** здесь проявляется в том, что **количество сообщений** в базе при последующих операциях **остаётся неизменным**. Касательно ссылок - карта сайта будет оставаться неизменной. Будет обновляться лишь содержимое тем.

или: каждый запрос `POST /article/hello` будет **создавать** новую главу в статье hello. Первый запрос создаст саму статью.

каждый запрос `PUT /article/hello` будет **обновлять** ЕДИНСТВЕННУЮ главу в статье hello. Первый запрос создаст саму статью.

Вот, что нам должен возвращать GET, если мы делали POST

```
GET /topic/hello 201
Здесь был Вася
```

В этом случае у нас также будут доступны и эти URI

```
GET /topic/hello/1 201
Здесь
GET /topic/hello/2 201
был
GET /topic/hello/3 201
Вася
```

Вот, что нам должен вернуть GET, если мы делали PUT

```
GET /topic/hello 201
Вася
```

В этом случае у нас будет доступна только одна URI

```
GET /topic/hello/1 201
Вася
GET /topic/hello/2 404
GET /topic/hello/3 404
```

**EXAMPLE #2** Пример с пользователями.

```
POST /user/eugen?age=7
POST /user/eugen?age=10
POST /user/eugen?age=5
```

Создаст 3 пользователя с именем eugen и возрастом 7, 10, 5, соответственно.

```
PUT /user/eugen?age=7
PUT /user/eugen?age=10
PUT /user/eugen?age=5
```

Будет создан только один пользователь с именем eugen с возрастом 5

Другими словами: PUT **обязан обновлять** запись, если данные уже есть

Отсюда и Ваш пример `String userId = this.request["USER_ID"];` с сохранением значения в переменной. Сколько раз вы бы не ложили (**PUT**) значения в переменную - переменная всегда будет одна.

Отсюда родился **EXAMPLE #3**

Не знаю на сколько эта аналогия верна, но думаю это утверждение будет верно:

```
POST: push $variable, value; -- в итоге массив значений
PUT:  $variable =  value; -- в итоге одно значение
```

в случае POST, вред, который может возникнут, это переполнится память сервера. В случае PUT - никакого вреда нет, только такты забираются ;-)

Кстати, вот нашел хороший ресурс, по поводу безопасности и идемпотентности
http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/

Comment: Но судя по  http://stackoverflow.com/a/630475/1791282 

POST: Used to modify and update a resource
PUT: Used to create a resource, or overwrite it. While you specify the resources new URL.

Comment: Как я и говорил - http://habrahabr.ru/qa/23936/
POST - для создания, PUT - для обновления. Вообще, нет никакой разницы. Все равно обработчики запросов вы пишете сами. И можете переопределить, что при PUT у вас сначала проевряется на наличие объекта, если есть - перезаписать, иначе - создать.

То же самое с POST

Answer (score 3):

> Создаст 3 пользователя с именем eugen и возрастом 7, 10, 5,
> соответственно.
>
> ```
> PUT /user/eugen?age=7
> PUT /user/eugen?age=10
> PUT /user/eugen?age=5
> ```

Мне кажется это не правильно спроектированное Api , Put -  должен быть идемпотентен , но  при создании api обычно возвращает 201 код а при Update  200 т.ё. create/update  нельзя  делать  put.

#### IMHO

- Post<=> Create/Update
- Put<=> Update

#### И семантически

PUT /user/eugen?age=7 -  установить евгену возраст 7  а ни как не создать 7-ми летнего Евгена.
Тогда http ответ должен быть либо 404 если евген не найден либо 200 если всё удачно поапдейтилось.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, это  обычно используется для api, скажем делаем PUT на url http://rest.mysite.com/documents/balance_2012 , как следует из семантики мы создаем документ если его нет, если есть, то выдаем ошибку, при POST документ обновится, если есть, а если нет - ошибка, но в современном мире всеми этими вещами управляет логика основанная не на url а на содержании пакета, так, что я лично предпочитаю api основанные на POST, т.к. все равно все случаи применения апи не покроешь именами методов рекомендуемыми спецификацией протокола.

Comment: @eicto Утверждение о современном мире и упралении на основе содержания пакета не кажется мне корректным. Большинство популярных API реализованы как RESTful-сервисы, в которых операции над данными определеяются как раз с помощью метода, а содержание пакета - всего-лишь представляет данные.

Comment: согласен, я говорил о проектировании api, с put сталкивался в api kayako