# Как создать глобальный счетчик, который будет увеличиваться при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть кнопка `submit` , при нажатии на которую счетчик будет увеличиваться на 1 (`count++;`). Необходимо сделать так, чтобы этот счетчик записывался на сервер и никаким образом не мог изменяться пользователем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: ajax, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно привязать обработчик к кнопке, который будет составлять и отправлять запрос на сервер. Для этого лучше всего использовать AJAX запросы. В том случае, если Вы используете библиотеку jQuery в своем проекте, то у вас запрос можно составить в очень короткой и понятной форме:

```
$.ajax({
    type: PUT, // тип запроса
    url: '/api/gCounter', // URL запроса
    data: { value: gCounter }, // параметры запроса
    timeout: 5000 // время, в течении которого функция будет ждать ответа от сервера, указывается в мс
}).done(function (response) {
    // обработчик, вызывающийся при успешном выполнении запроса
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // обработчик, вызывающийся при ошибке
});
```

В противном случае можно сделать все это на Javascript без использования сторонних библиотек ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531927/ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-put-%D0%B8-delete-%D0%B2-javascript))

Comment: Зачем `PUT`, можно и `POST`; А без сторонних библиотек есть `fetch`

Comment: Во-первых, `PUT` является идемпотентным, что означает, что можно отправить множество запросов на один и тот же URL ([just to know](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/193988/381650)). Во-вторых, FetchAPI будет обрабатывать запросы с кодом 404 и 500 как `OK` ([первоисточник на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)) и в принципе начинающему будет очень полезно знать как составляется запрос без использования сторонних API и библиотек.

Comment: По условию `counter++` , который как раз не идемпотентный `POST`.

Comment: `500` -- это прикладной уровень, а на сетевом всё действительно ок.
Соответственно, да, надо отдельно на `2xx` проверять.
И FetchAPI -- наименее сторонний (для современных браузеров).

Comment: Нет, можно конечно слать `GET` и сразу `PUT` (`current+1` на клиенте)